Why were only men allowed to divorce for sexual impurity? Did men not also commit sexual misconduct?
Note: this question was posted to Biblical Hermeneutics yesterday, and did not attract a response. As this is a question about the Law of Moses, I'm open to a Jewish explanation as well. This question seems related, though not the same; but I am looking for a more Bible-focused explanation, as the rest of additional Jewish traditions are unfamiliar to me: Can a wife demand a divorce from a cheating husband.
In Deuteronomy 22 and 24, only men were allowed to produce a bill of divorce. Although in the case of adultery, both sexes are criminally responsible, in the case of Deuteronomy 22 and 24, there does not seem to be an equivalent law for women finding such uncleanness in their husband.

(Deuteronomy 24:1, Koren trans.) When a man has taken a wife, and married her, and it come to pass that she find no favour in his eyes, because he has found some unseemliness in her: then let him write her a bill of divorce, and give it in her hand, and send her out of his house.
(Deuteronomy 22:13-15, Koren trans.) If any man take a wife, and go in to her, and hate her,
and lay accusing speeches against her, and bring out an evil name upon her, saying, I took this woman, and when I came to her, I found her not to be a virgin:
then shall the father of the girl, and her mother, take and bring forth the tokens of the girl’s virginity to the elders of the city in the gate

It is my understanding that rabbis generally also allowed women to divorce their husbands. That is a broader issue. But the more specific question is, could there not be uncleanness found in a man, as in general sexual indecency, impropriety, or something of the like, which, though not at the level of adultery (for which the punishment is death), would legally allow divorce -- a male equivalent to women's purity laws? And if not, why not?
Obviously the Bible is not completely egalitarian, but I wonder how to address this in today's context, where this is seen as a slight against women, who would not have had the same recourse as men. How do theologians explain this apparent unfairness towards women?
Duplicate note:
The following duplicate has been suggested: In adultery, why is a wife is guilty, and a husband not?. The proposed duplicate asks why the husband is not guilty. My question asks why the wife has no recourse.
Related questions:
Did Moses compromise by allowing the Israelites to divorce in Deutoronomy 24:1?
What does the phrase "uncleanliness in her" refer to in Deuteronomy 24:1?

Hi, @Denis, it's great to have you here with us! The answers to this question should clear things up for you : In adultery, why is a wife is guilty, and a husband not?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@יהושעק in my understanding, my question is not about adultery, because the punishment for adultery is death, whereas here we have a different case of impurity before or during marriage, that, while constituting infidelity, is not to the same degree that would lead to death by stoning.

Very interesting point, @Denis. In order for the death penalty to apply, a whole series of conditions (such as witnesses to the act and prior warnings) would need to be met, which is a pretty rare occurrence

@יהושעק if that is the case, as the law itself does not seem to indicate such a rationale, (since a woman has clearly committed adultery, but the man cannot be found), it might be interesting to find sources for such an indication. I was personally perceiving public indecency, perhaps exotic dancing, or the lack of virginity before marriage, as potential points of divorce, which is different from adultery per se.

The Talmud has plenty of cases where the husband is at-fault. If there was an egregious misunderstanding about his present state at the time of the wedding, the whole wedding is null and void. The Talmud she can demand a divorce in cases of psychological abuse ("I demand you tell our neighbor what we did in the bedroom last night"; "I demand you go fill up this bucket from the well and then pour it out, twenty times") or even just medical conditions that make him unbearable.

As for him cheating on her, as was linked above, he was allowed to have a second wife, so the law could clearly say "she can't sleep with anyone else", but couldn't say "he can't sleep with anyone else." Anyhow. Deuteronomy focuses on a problem with the wife because a Jewish divorce requires him to write (or instruct a scribe to write) a document and hand it to her. In cases of abuse (let's assume they developed later in the marriage), the Talmud would say the rabbis step in and order him to hand her a divorce. In the US today, this means protestors outside his house.

... and synagogues refusing him entry. In Israel today (where failure to perform a religious ritual can trigger the levers of the state), that could mean he loses his passport, driver's license, and ability to use banks -- essentially he has to live "cash-only" as a stateless person. It's quite effective, when/if implemented.

@יהושעק I have added a note to explain my rationale as to why both questions, why addressing the same topic, are not the same.

A woman who cheats on her husband is forbidden to him, whereas a man who cheats on his wife is not forbidden to her.

B"H
First, that reference from Deuteronomy 22:13-15 (really extending to -20 and on) is talking about a case where she cheated on him after becoming engaged to him but before marrying him, which is a capital offense.
Rashi ibid:20


But if this matter was true: [indeed,] no evidence of the girl's virginity was found.     כ. וְאִם־אֱמֶ֣ת הָיָ֔ה הַדָּבָ֖ר הַזֶּ֑ה
לֹֽא־נִמְצְא֥וּ בְתוּלִ֖ים לַנַּֽעֲרָֽה (כתיב לנער)

But if this
matter was true: [as corroborated] by witnesses, and there was
warning, [proving] that she had committed adultery after her
betrothal. — [Keth. 44b]
וְאִם־אֱמֶת הָיָה הַדָּבָר: בְּעֵדִים וְהַתְרָאָה, שֶׁזִּנְּתָה
לְאַחַר אֵרוּסִין (כתובות מ"ד):

According to Torah law, a man is allowed to have more than one wife, but not the other way around. There's no unique "sin" for a man to commit adultery as there is for a woman (besides for the other sins involved for having relations with someone he's not married to/a niddah etc), although if he does cheat on her then that is grounds for her to initiate a divorce (see later).
In terms of being "fair" and "moral": morality is defined by the Creator. He made everything, He decides what's good and what's bad.
The Rambam tells us that all of the laws of forbidden relationships are known as chukim, Mitzvos who's reasoning is not known to us.
They have deep spiritual reasons, some that only the Creator knows about, but not all of them can be understood by the intellect of created beings.
The Rambam does say that however much reason one can give these commandments, one should give (end of h. Meila), but (ibid) the main reason of them is still hidden from us.
In terms of a woman being able to divorce a man because of immodest behavior, many rabbis say that if she simply doesn't want to continue being with him then she can initiate a divorce, especially if the man has been involved excessively with other women, even when no adultery was found.

A woman may demand a divorce from her husband, if he has been found to
be philandering with other women. There need not be proof of his
having committed adultery, just of his having cavorted with other
women. Even his causing her a bad name through his lecherous actions
is likewise considered legitimate justification for the wife launching
a divorce action. If the wife feels repulsed by her husband, it is
wrong to force her to remain in the union

Now to the question of what specifically is meant by "immodest behavior" by the women, the Rambam references the verse in hilchos geirushin 10:20-22:

22 It is a mitzvah to divorce a woman who possesses unsavory character
traits and does not conduct herself modestly73, as is the practice of
proper daughters of Israel, as [implied by Proverbs 22:10]: "Drive
away the scoffer, and contention will depart."


When a woman has been divorced for loose moral conduct,74 it is not
fitting for a proper man to marry her, lest people say: "This one sent
away this wicked woman, and this one brought her home."
כב אִשָּׁה רָעָה בְּדֵעוֹתֶיהָ וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ צְנוּעָה כִּבְנוֹת
יִשְׂרָאֵל הַכְּשֵׁרוֹת מִצְוָה לְגָרְשָׁהּ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (משלי כב י)
״‎גָּרֵשׁ לֵץ וְיֵצֵא מָדוֹן״‎. וְאִשָּׁה שֶׁנִּתְגָּרְשָׁה מִשּׁוּם
פְּרִיצוּת אֵין רָאוּי לְאָדָם כָּשֵׁר שֶׁיִּשָּׂאֶנָּה. שֶׁלֹּא
יֹאמְרוּ זֶה הוֹצִיא רְשָׁעָה מִבֵּיתוֹ וְזֶה מַכְנִיסָהּ:

And in hilchos ishus 24:11-12 the Rambam explains exactly what is meant:

11 The following are the actions for which a woman is considered to
have "violated the faith of Moses":
a) going out to the marketplace with her hair uncovered;25
b) taking vows or oaths that she does not keep;
c) engaging in sexual relations [with her husband] while in the niddah
state;
d) failing to separate challah or feeding her husband food that is
forbidden to eat - needless to say, this applies to forbidden crawling
animals and animals that were not ritually slaughtered; it applies
even to produce that was not tithed.26
How can the latter [two] matters be known? For example, she said: "So
and so, the priest, [separated tithes] from this produce for me," "So
and so separated challah [from this dough]," "So and so, the Sage,
said this stain does not render me a niddah" - and after eating the
food or engaging in sexual relations with her, the husband asked the
person whose name was mentioned and he denied the occurrence of the
incident. Another example: a woman's [conduct caused] it to be
established in her neighborhood that she was in the niddah state,27
but she told her husband that she was ritually pure. He engaged in
relations with her [and afterwards discovered the truth].
יא וְאֵלּוּ הֵן הַדְּבָרִים שֶׁאִם עָשְׂתָה אַחַת מֵהֶן עָבְרָה עַל
דַּת משֶׁה. יוֹצְאָה בַּשּׁוּק וּשְׂעַר רֹאשָׁהּ גָּלוּי. אוֹ
שֶׁנּוֹדֶרֶת אוֹ שֶׁנִּשְׁבַּעַת וְאֵינָהּ מְקַיֶּמֶת. אוֹ
שֶׁשִּׁמְּשָׁה מִטָּתָהּ וְהִיא נִדָּה. אוֹ שֶׁאֵינָהּ קוֹצָה לָהּ
חַלָּה. אוֹ שֶׁהֶאֱכִילָה אֶת בַּעְלָהּ דְּבָרִים אֲסוּרִים, אֵין
צָרִיךְ לוֹמַר שְׁקָצִים וּרְמָשִׂים וּנְבֵלוֹת, אֶלָּא דְּבָרִים
שֶׁאֵינָן מְעֻשָּׂרִין. וְהֵיאַךְ יוֹדֵעַ דָּבָר זֶה כְּגוֹן
שֶׁאָמְרָה לוֹ פֵּרוֹת אֵלּוּ פְּלוֹנִי כֹּהֵן תִּקְּנָם לִי וְעִסָּה
זוֹ פְּלוֹנִית הִפְרִישָׁה לִי חַלָּתָהּ וּפְלוֹנִי הֶחָכָם טִהֵר לִי
אֶת הַכֶּתֶם וְאַחַר שֶׁאָכַל אוֹ בָּא עָלֶיהָ שָׁאַל אוֹתוֹ פְּלוֹנִי
וְאָמַר לֹא הָיוּ דְּבָרִים מֵעוֹלָם. וְכֵן אִם הֻחְזְקָה נִדָּה
בִּשְׁכֵנוֹתֶיהָ וְאָמְרָה לְבַעְלָהּ טְהוֹרָה אֲנִי וּבָא עָלֶיהָ:
12 What is meant by "the Jewish faith"? The customs of modesty that
Jewish women practice. When a woman performs any of the following
acts, she is considered to have violated the Jewish faith:
a) she goes to the marketplace or a lane with openings at both ends
without having her head [fully] covered - i.e., her hair is covered by
a handkerchief, but not with a veil like all other women,28
b) she spins [flax or wool] with a rose on her face29 - on her
forehead or on her cheek - like immodest gentile women,
c) she spins in the marketplace and shows her forearms to men;30
d) she plays frivolously with young lads,
e) she demands sexual intimacy from her husband in a loud voice until
her neighbors hear her talking about their intimate affairs, or
f) she curses her husband's father in her husband's presence.31
יב וְאֵי זוֹ הִיא דָּת יְהוּדִית הוּא מִנְהַג הַצְּנִיעוּת שֶׁנָּהֲגוּ
בְּנוֹת יִשְׂרָאֵל. וְאֵלּוּ הֵן הַדְּבָרִים שֶׁאִם עָשְׂתָה אַחַת
מֵהֶן עָבְרָה עַל דָּת יְהוּדִית. יוֹצְאָה לַשּׁוּק אוֹ לְמָבוֹי
מְפֻלָּשׁ וְרֹאשָׁהּ פָּרוּעַ וְאֵין עָלֶיהָ רְדִיד כְּכָל הַנָּשִׁים.
אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁשְּׂעָרָהּ מְכֻסֶּה בְּמִטְפַּחַת. אוֹ שֶׁהָיְתָה
טוֹוָה בַּשּׁוּק וּוֶרֶד וְכַיּוֹצֵא בּוֹ כְּנֶגֶד פָּנֶיהָ עַל
פַּדַּחְתָּהּ אוֹ עַל לְחָיֶיהָ כְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁעוֹשׂוֹת הָעַכּוּ''ם
הַפְּרוּצוֹת. אוֹ שֶׁטּוֹוָה בַּשּׁוּק וּמַרְאֵית זְרוֹעוֹתֶיהָ
לִבְנֵי אָדָם. אוֹ שֶׁהָיְתָה מְשַׂחֶקֶת עִם הַבַּחוּרִים. אוֹ
שֶׁהָיְתָה תּוֹבַעַת הַתַּשְׁמִישׁ בְּקוֹל רָם מִבַּעְלָהּ עַד
שֶׁשְּׁכֵנוֹתֶיהָ שׁוֹמְעוֹת אוֹתָהּ מְדַבֶּרֶת עַל עִסְקֵי
תַּשְׁמִישׁ. אוֹ שֶׁהָיְתָה מְקַלֶּלֶת אֲבִי בַּעְלָהּ בִּפְנֵי
בַּעְלָהּ:


My apologies, what is Rambam, h. Meila, Mitzvos? Is niddah state the time of menstrual impurity? What is challah? The rabbinic interpretations are interesting, but also seem rather arbitrary and not really supported by scripture (she goes to the market without wearing a viel, is that really a reason for divorce? Or wears perfume? Or shows her forearm? One would think that the law of Moses was there to stipulate limited causes for divorce, not open a litany of frivolous reasons.)

@DenisG.Labrecque these terms can be looked up, I recommend chabad.org or another Torah observant source. One fundamental principal in the Torah is that the written Torah was never intended to be read directly. The Creator gave us the explanation of the Torah at the same time He gave us the written Torah. Rambam mishneh Torah, introduction.

Even if your statement that "the written Torah was never intended to be read directly" is not scriptural per se, it is obvious that the law should have its interpreters: even Moses had his aides. But questions will naturally arise when the interpretation given runs against the intention of the law... Besides, this has been a point of dispute within Judaism -- see Shammai vs. Hillel.

@DenisG.Labrecque the explanation of the Torah was given to us by the Creator of the universe. Within that explanation, there are multiple correct views for each law. Hashem tells Moshe, mentioned in the midrash, that every law of the Torah has 49 interpretations in one direction, and 49 in another, inherently built into them by the Creator Himself. Then He told Moshe that the way to decide which one is practical is to follow the majority, and certain other rules. In some cases the Creator Himself allowed the great court to decide on their own which of the interpretations should be followed.

With all respect to tradition, as an outsider, this seems patently absurd and self-defeating. Any law that has two opposite interpretations is barely worthy of the title "suggestion", even less of "law". Imagine what chaos a country would be in if every law had 49 different and opposing interpretations.
I cannot in good conscience interpret Scripture/the law of Moses in that way.

@DenisG.Labrecque this answer is some utility: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/136448/31534. As is this: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136236/contradiction-in-the-torah-please-explain-this-i-have-heard-many-times-that-a/136248#136248. It's no skin off our back if you find this absurd, however I do feel like you haven't heard enough to jump to that conclusion yet and I would certainly recommend, for your own interest, to continue looking into this subject. Judaism is the world's oldest religion and we still have 1000 laws from Moses about Tefillin. We are doing something right

The verses you are quoting do not support your thesis that there is only a concept of "sexual decency" for women but not men. See Y DJ's answer for a basic Scriptual source that proves men are not allowed to be indecent, and there are many more.
The Torah is very concerned about marriages. A marriage is a sacred bond between a man and a woman. The Torah recognises that sometimes a marriage has lost certain qualities - including a solid bond between the husband and wife - and therefore it would be better that they are divorced rather than remain married.
The verses you are quoting are not providing any more information than the following:

A husband must initiate a divorce (24)
A husband must do so willingly (24)
A example of grounds for him to do so would be if he finds his wife to be repulsive (24, and the Torah is recognising that most men find sexual indecency in women to be repuslive, as an example)
If a woman tells her husband she is a virgin before marriage, and he discovers that she isn't, that is grounds for divorce (22 - see also Core of reality's answer regarding how this is related to actual adultery, rather than virginity - it is allowed for a Jew to marry a non-virgin)
Her family has the opportunity to prove her innocence, and clear her name (22).
If her innocence is proven, he is punished (22).

These are general principles and they do not imply anything about what a woman can and can't ask for a divorce for, so there is no use making presumptions. Indeed, looking at point 3) we can learn that if a woman finds her husband repulsive, she very likely has the right to demand a divorce, and courts will enforce it.
This can include him being sexually promiscuous, not providing her conjugal rights, not supporting her financially, losing a limb, or even developing bad breath! See SA EH 154.
It is fair to note that the Torah does concern itself with a woman's sexual purity more than a man's, but that is for several reasons that, again, do not imply that there is no such thing as indecency by men. It's partly legal, partly practical, and partly just recognition of basic human psychology - men and women's concerns are asymmetrical, but asymmetry does not imply bias or unfairness.

What would the reasoning be for concluding of finding someone repulsive by sexual indecency as an example (as commonly interpreted in Jewish circles), versus being one of the only allowed exceptions (as commonly interpreted in Christian circles)? For example, Jesus' commentary is, "Whoever divorces his wife and marries another commits adultery; and whoever marries her who is divorced from her husband commits adultery" when commenting on the divorce for "any" reason. This would seem to preserve the marriage relationship as required by the spirit of the law.

Now you're saying "hey the Christian reading is right, what's wrong with you Jews?" Wrong website. The vision is simple -- if people are truly incompatible, they should end the relationship and go find happiness elsewhere.

@DenisG.Labrecque I can't speak for Christianity, but Beit Shammai holds, from this verse, that a man may not divorce his wife unless he finds out she is cheating, translating "unseemly thing" literally as "a matter of nakedness". Beit Hillel holds that he can divorce her for almost any reason because he sees the statement "doesn't find favour in his eyes" and "finds an unseemly thing" as separated by "or", not "and", which is viable in Hebrew (Gittin 9:10, Bartenura there).

@RabbiKaii right, I'm actually familiar with that debate, and it makes sense as the Hebrew conjunction is contextual (in my understanding, I do not read). So "if he finds his wife repulsive" might represent the more Hellelite school of thought ("if even she burns dinner, or he find someone prettier than she" type of idea)?

@DenisG.Labrecque you seem to be quoting the mishna. Beit Hillel recognises 3 reasons from this: 1) cheating 2) something offensive 3) he is not attracted to her anymore (explained above re: "or" vs "and"). The way we get the split between 1 and 2 is through the rules of exegesis - the phrase "naked matter" (i.e. "something repulsive" as you put it) is unusual and unnecessary in Hebrew, so it is to be split into a) something involving "nakedness" (cheating etc) or b) any other "matter" that is offensive (burning food etc). Does that help?

The best way to understand this split is the split between justice, and justice combined with mercy, Shammai and Hillel's approaches respectively. Ultimately according to truth and justice, God needs a husband and wife, who are two halves of a whole soul, to remain together. We mortal, fallible humans, need to sometimes get divorced, so God created the concept of divorce because He is merciful and considerate towards us. The halacha is like Hillel during this "period of mercy", in almost all cases. I.e. He is good, in that He puts us first, even in His law.

There is a clear prohibition for promiscuity Devarim 23:18 for both men and women:
לֹא־תִהְיֶ֥ה קְדֵשָׁ֖ה מִבְּנ֣וֹת יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל וְלֹֽא־יִהְיֶ֥ה קָדֵ֖שׁ מִבְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃
There shall be no Jewish woman promiscuous/prostitute, and not a Jewish man be promiscuous/prostitute.
The understanding of the words קָדֵ֖שׁ / קְדֵשָׁ֖ה may have association with ancient cults like Babylonian Ishtar, but in modern times it seems to be interpreted as promiscuous on the OU website https://outorah.org/p/6168. I do not know if this is strong enough to be grounds for divorce, especially when either a man or a woman can do teshuvah.
